# My crumb cake topping isn't working

Tags: cake

I used margarine instead of butter and the margarine was mostly at room temp.  So I used a pasty cutter turned the bowl but the mixture just got thicker and thicker.  Is there something I can do to save the mixture to make it crumbly or a recipe I can make instead?  I used 2 cups flour and sugar and 1/2 butter along with the other dry ingredients

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the mixture crumbly is to cut the margarine into pieces, then freeze the pieces while making the main part of the recipe, then use the frozen pieces in the topping.